# New computer build will not install windows 7

Tags: windows-7

So I recently got a computer built for me, I purchased the parts and a friend of mine who's built computers for a liveing built it. 
First issue. My old hard drive would not boot up windows, and would not recognize the keyboard and mouse after windows repair started up. Ok, so I purchased a new hardrive. Put that in and tried to install windows 7 (I planned on upgrading to ten asoon as I got it running as I have a key for 7) it will not recognize a usb with windows, nor a burned windows disk no matter how many times I go in a tell it to boot from disk. 
Here are my parts.

AMD Ryzen 5 2600 6-Core/12-Thread Processor Socket AM4 3.40GHz Base/ 3.90 GHz Boost, Wraith Stealth cooler 65W

GIGABYTE Radeon RX 590 GAMING 8GB 1560 MHz Boost, 8000 MHz Memory PCI-E 3.0, DVI-D, HDMI 2.0, 3x

GIGABYTE X470 AORUS Ultra Gaming Socket AMD AM4 X470 Chipset Dual Channel DDR4, PCI-E 3.0, SATA 6.0Gb/s, M.2 USB 3.0 Motherboard

Seagate BarraCuda 2TB SATA 3.5'' 7200RPM Desktop Hard Drive

Comment: How are you making the USB or disc? It’s been a while since I’ve done this, but unless something has changed you can install Windows 10 directly and activate with the Win 7 key. An install disc is made with the windows media creation tool.

Comment: My friend is the one that has been makeing them,  maybe a windows 10 disk would work of that is the case!!

Comment: Get drivers from https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X470-AORUS-ULTRA-GAMING-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver for proper OS, download and install.

Comment: Sounds like you should be asking your friend, and not us. I hope that you ddn't pay him

Comment: No I didn't, there's no need to be rude, I have been asking him , he's stumped too.      Iam unsure how I can install other drivers when I can't even install a operating system yet.

Comment: Is the system in UEFI or CCSM mode?

Answer (score 1):

It can be 3 possible problems;

1. You fail to state what kind of usb mouse/keyboard you have. If cordless with a usb receiver it sometime need a driver to work inside Windows. Please use a simple keyboard with a cord to rule that out.
2. Did you use the USB connector on the backside of the computer ? Often front panel USB cable plug are not always plugged in on the motherboard. Make sure the numluck led work to rule that out.
3. Last thing make sure the USB channel are not disabled inside your BIOS, if not, and all other tip didn't worked, you might had received a motherboard with bad USB connector. To rule that out you can use a bootable linux dvd to simply boot the computer and see if the usb device would work.

Comment: 1.I use corded  usb keyboard and mouse. They work fine unless I try to run Windows repair on the old hard drive. 2. The front usb are not hooked up so I don't use them 3. I've already been fiddling with the bios in hopes I could get the first harddrive to work but alas, it didn't improve things :(

Comment: @Lixystrange The windows repair is a minimum gui, but in the install it didnt work too ? If so I would simply use a win10 disk then to install

Comment: It wouldn't even read the usb or disk as a bootable device. Agreed, I will try to get my hands on a windows 10 disk and try that